# How to achieve this effect that looks smoky/blurred and was used in a Balenciaga campaign?

Tags: filters, effect, soft-focus

This effect looks like smoke with a little blurring. There are many examples of this because it has been used in some erotic movies.

I don’t know if it’s a lens filter, a specific camera, a technique, or a type of film. How is this effect achieved?

[image: example image 1]
[image: example image 2]
[image: example image 3]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the 70s that effect was called 'flu', and was made putting cellophane or similar in the front of the lens.

Some photographers used a plain filter with vaseline or even a piece of pantyhose.

Comment: Pantyhose will also make stars on the highlights.

Comment: The vaseline trick works well.  If you left the centre of the filter clear then you could control the degree of blur with your iris.  wide open = more blur.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easy enough in post-processing.
In Darktable the 'bloom' effect would give a similar result, in combination with suitable masks (to limit the area and strenght of the effect, like in the first image). I'm not using photoshop, so I can't give any details for that program.